# Android: App crashes at startup - attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed

Tags: android, crash

I copied an existing app that worked and stripped out all the stuff I didn't need to create a minimal version of some feature. The app compiles but crashes when it runs. I tried using LogCat but all I get is:

attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed

Not very useful. I had this problem in the past when I copied a project and stripped out stuff but was able to figure out the problem. But that was long ago and can't remember what the problem was. Checked my manifest but couldn't see anything. Any clues? Thanks a lot!

FOLLOW UP:
Turns out that the name attribute in the manifest causes the problem:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="false">
```

Removing it fixes the problem. Don't know why this should be a problem.

Comment: OK, I came across another post that says they solved this by removing the name attribute in the manifest file. I did that and it worked. Why?? When I copied the project, I gave this attribute a new name. So why should that be a problem?

Comment: Which name attribute? What was it, and what did you change it to?

Comment: See my FOLLOW UP in the original post.

Comment: My App has no name tag in the manifest file.But it shows me the same error. I was using Handler class to do some network operation on different thread.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to

- clean project ( menu Project -> Clean ) and
- fix android properties (Right click on project name in sidebar left -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties ) ?

Sometimes it fixes everything!